# Entity Framework Code First use SQL Server datetime2 instead of datetime everywhere

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-2012

I know this can be accomplished using the Fluent API on a single property, but I want to have this automatically happen for everywhere I use a .NET DateTime in my model. Here's an example of doing a single property:

`modelBuilder.Entity<T>()
            .Property(f => f.MyDateTimeProperty)
            .HasColumnType("datetime2");`

But instead of only on this one property I want it to happen everywhere automatically. There is a fix for this in Model First by editing the T4 generation template so I know it can be done there but I need the same thing in Code First.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a Custom Code First Convention.

There's an example of exactly what you are trying to do here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx